DAG to read a BQ table and then creates multiple exports based on batch name in the batch_name column
Very new to my learning in Airflow.
Im looking to create a DAG which reads a BQ table and then creates multiple exports based on the batch name in the batch_name column, there will be no set number of batch names each time this will run.
The exports should be as .csv and will export into GCS
Currently using:
composer-2.6.5-airflow-2.7.3
Python version: 3
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryOperator
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['xxxxxxxxxx@xxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 4, 1),
    'schedule_interval': '0 9 1 * *',
}

dag = DAG(
    'automated_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='This DAG',
    catchup=False
)

table_name = '`mydataset.mytable`'

read_table_task = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='read_bigquery_table',
    sql=f'SELECT * FROM {table_name}',
    dag=dag
)

def get_unique_batch_names(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_bigquery_table')
    # Parse the JSON string back to a list of dictionaries
    data = eval(data)
    batch_names = set(row['batch_name'] for row in data)
    return list(batch_names)

get_batch_names_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_unique_batch_names',
    python_callable=get_unique_batch_names,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

def export_to_gcs_for_batch(batch_name, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_bigquery_table')
    # Parse the JSON string back to a list of dictionaries
    data = eval(data)
    filtered_data = [row for row in data if row['batch_name'] == batch_name]
    gcs_uri = f'gs://batches/{batch_name}_{datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")}.csv'
    with open(gcs_uri, 'w') as f:
        # Write data to file
        for row in filtered_data:
            f.write(','.join(str(value) for value in row.values()) + '\n')  # Example: Write each row as comma-separated values
    return gcs_uri

batch_names = get_batch_names_task.output

export_tasks = []
for batch_name in batch_names:
    export_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'export_to_gcs_{batch_name}',
        python_callable=export_to_gcs_for_batch,
        op_kwargs={'batch_name': batch_name},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )
    export_tasks.append(export_task)

read_table_task >> get_batch_names_task >> export_tasks`


